# Parsing valid url from long string with pure js or jquery using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I get a longString from object's onclick value

```
var longString = String(this.onclick);
```

output like below;

> function onclick(event) { window.location.href = "index.html?q1=v1&g2=v2"; }

I want parse that like below:

```
index.html?q1=v1&g2=v2
```

How can I do this with pure js or jquery which works with all browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it if you don't like regular expressions.

```
var str = 'function onclick(event) { window.location.href = "index.html?q1=v1&g2=v2"; }';
var idx = str.indexOf('"')+1;
var res = str.substr(idx, str.lastIndexOf('"') - idx );
```

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/Tk8aw/

Comment: thank you. this code works with ff but does'nt work with ie. Actuallly firstly i get this string from onclick like this  var longString = String(this.onclick); after that i want to parse it.

Comment: @Kerberos - Which version of IE? Works for me just fine. And are you saying that the string actually starts with `"window.location..."`? It should still work.

Comment: but i get this string value from object onclick value when codes run. i don't manipulate like i wrote. i edited my post. may be that clear more.

Comment: @Kerberos - I don't get it. Are you getting the `onclick` of the element that was clicked? Either way, should work. Could you post the actual code so I can see what you mean? Here's another example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tk8aw/3/

Comment: Patrick, OK. i found problem's source. FF output to string onclick value with " character but ie output to string with ' character. when replace to " to ' problem solved.
Thank you very much for your help. regards kerberos.

Answer (score 2):

[parseUri](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The following will extract the first match from any one line function (regardless of the name or spacing):

```
var input = "function onclick(event) { window.location.href = \"index.html?q1=v1&g2=v2\"; }";
var pattern = /function\s+\w+\(\w*\)\s*{\s*window.location.href\s*=\s*['"]([^'"]*)['"];\s*}/i;
var output = pattern.exec(input);
```

After this runs, the `index.html...` part will be in `output[1]`

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for

```
var str = 'function onclick(event) { window.location.href = "index.html?q1=v1&g2=v2"; }';
alert( /".+?"/.exec(str) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab it using a regex like this:

```
var string = 'function onclick(event) { window.location.href = "index.html?q1=v1&g2=v2"; }';
var url = string.match(/"(.*?)"/)[1];
alert(url); // == index.html?q1=v1&g2=v2, without quotes​​​​​​​​​​
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/j3Kk7/), be aware that the regex returns an object, to get the actual string you're probably after the second entry, `[1]` here.

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't do any parsing, but instead declares its own `window.location.href`, evals the given code, so the `onclick` becomes a defined function within the scope of this function, runs it, so our *local* `window.location.href` gets updated and then returns it. It assumes the contents of the string are *known*, *safe* and similar to what you've already given.

```
function extractURL(code) {
    var window = { location: { href: '' } };
    eval(code);
    onclick();
    return window.location.href;
}
```

Example use,

```
var fn = 'function onclick(event) { window.location.href = "index.html?q1=v1&g2=v2"; }';
extractURL(fn); // "index.html?q1=v1&g2=v2"
```